# How to get all request parameters in Play and Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

```
 case GET(Path("/rtb_v1/bidrequest")) => Action {  implicit request =>
```

I want to take the request object above and get all of the key/value pairs sent in the form post and flatten it into a Map[String,String]

i have gone through all the documents and am at a dead end.

This is pretty freaking easy in Java/Servlets I;m wondering why there is no documentation on a simple thing like this anywhere..

```
Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Play's equivalent of `request.getParamterMap` is `request.queryString`, which returns a `Map[String, Seq[String]]`. You can flatten it to a `Map[String, String]` with

```
request.queryString.map { case (k,v) => k -> v.mkString }
```

[And here is the documentation.](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request)

Comment: works.. i like this code its a little more expressive than flatmap solutions

Comment: Can you assign now the queryString to another request and how?

Comment: wow.. I am new to scala, would you mind explaining how your `map` `case` can return a `map[string, string]`?

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to the way that Kim does it, I personally use a function like..

```
def param(field: String): Option[String] = 
  request.queryString.get(field).flatMap(_.headOption)
```

Answer (score 2):

It won't work if request is using POST method. Following code can be used:

```
req.body match {
  case AnyContentAsFormUrlEncoded(params) ⇒
    println(s"urlEncoded = $params")
  case mp @ AnyContentAsMultipartFormData(_) ⇒
    println(s"multipart = ${mp.asFormUrlEncoded}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the following:

```
request.queryString.map { case (k,v) => k -> v.mkString }).toSeq: _*
```